# What is the equivalent of runas /netonly in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, kerberos, powershell-5.0

Is it possible to start a program from Powershell using different Kerberos token for network access from the one used to start the program as you would do using `runas /netonly`?

Comment: I know this is an old question but there is a RunAs module on Powershell Gallery: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RunAs/1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell does have a RunAs option, when you use cmdlets that have it.

For example:

[Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)

There are several articles that have been around for some time on what you are trying to accomplish. As of course, this query has come up before.

> [RunAS /netony - PowerShell equivalent ?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ad087137-50de-46f4-852d-727c2edbe172/runas-netony-powershell-equivalent-)

```
# You can't use 'runas' directly in Powershell.  Anyway as you know, Runas will prompt for a password. 

# To run a program with different credentials in Powershell is a two-part process:

# 1. Store the password interactively to an encoded text file:


$credential = Get-Credential 'targetDomain\user'
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\scripts\password.txt
```

> [Using a PowerShell script to run as a different user & elevate the
>   process.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benshy/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-elevate-the-process)

```
# The script:

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "TestDomain\Me" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"

<#
The following section starts the PowerShell command-line process with Start-Process 
prompting for user credentials. You may not need this dependent on UAC settings, 
as you might already get an over-the-shoulder prompt for creds during elevation. 
#> 

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "TestDomain\Me"

# The -NoNewWindow parameter re-uses the same PowerShell command window.
```

> [Run a command as a different user in Powershell](https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-command-as-a-different-user-in-powershell)
>
> There are three main ways to run a command as a different user in
>   Powershell, besides the classing Right click shift. This article will
>   show you how to do that, within the same Powershell session.

Here is a script to download and dissect as needed.

- [PowerShell function to runas a different user](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-to-3e9766e3/file/54966/1/PowerShellRunAs.ps1)

See also:

> [RunAs 1.3](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RunAs/1.3)
>
> A version of the Windows 'runas' command that accepts a
>   PSCredential instead of prompting for a password.

Comment: The OP asked specifically about the `/netonly` parameter of `runas`. The way `/netonly` works is that it receives credentials at the time `runas` is executed. However, those credentials are not validated at this time. Instead, they are applied only when the program that `runas` launched tries to access the network.

This is different from what cmdlets such as `Start-Process` do when you add a `-Credential` argument. In this case, the credentials are evaluated immediately. This can cause an authentication failure, and this error can prevent the process from launching.